# How do I get syntax highlighting of data bound JS variables?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding, syntax-highlighting

In visual studio I am working with an ASP.NET project and using knockout.js to databind observables to the view. If I miss a letter in the name of one of these data bound variables, I have to wait till runtime before finding these problems.

Does a tool exist (doesn't have to be visual studio) to solve my problem and if not, why?

Here is an example where intellisense would be useful when databinding.

```
<div data-bind="component: Re"></div>

<script>
    function ViewModel()
    {
        var Red = bla bla bla
    } 
</script>
```